# All goroutines are asleep - deadlock. Can't find a reason why

Tags: go, deadlock

A following program try to compute the total size of all files in the current directory (`Size` method of the `sizer` structure). Can't figure out why I get this error message.

```
package storage

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

const MAX_GOROUTINES = 5

// Result represents the Size function result
type Result struct {
    // Total Size of File objects
    Size int64
    // Count is a count of File objects processed
    Count int64
}

type DirSizer interface {
    // Size calculate a size of given Dir, receive a ctx and the root Dir instance
    // will return Result or error if happened
    Size(ctx context.Context, d Dir) (Result, error)
}

// sizer implement the DirSizer interface
type sizer struct {
    // maxWorkersCount number of workers for asynchronous run
    maxWorkersCount int
}

// NewSizer returns new DirSizer instance
func NewSizer() DirSizer {
    return &sizer{MAX_GOROUTINES}
}

func Worker(ctx context.Context, errorQueue chan error, dirQueue chan Dir, globalRes *Result,
    mutex *sync.Mutex, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            if len(dirQueue) == 0 {
                close(dirQueue)
                return
            }
            cur, ok := <-dirQueue
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            dirs, files, err := cur.Ls(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                errorQueue <- err
                close(errorQueue)
                return
            }
            res := Result{}
            for _, f := range files {
                fileSize, err := f.Stat(ctx)
                if err != nil {
                    errorQueue <- err
                    close(errorQueue)
                    return
                }
                res.Size += fileSize
                res.Count++
            }
            mutex.Lock()
            globalRes.Size += res.Size
            globalRes.Count += res.Count
            mutex.Unlock()
            for _, d := range dirs {
                dirQueue <- d
            }
            continue
        }
    }
}

func (a *sizer) Size(ctx context.Context, d Dir) (Result, error) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    mutex := sync.Mutex{}
    errorQueue := make(chan error, 1)
    dirQueue := make(chan Dir)
    res := Result{}
    dirQueue <- d
    for i := 0; i < a.maxWorkersCount; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go Worker(ctx, errorQueue, dirQueue, &res, &mutex, &wg)
    }
    err := <-errorQueue
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Print(res)
    return res, err
}
```

I tried to replace unbuffered channel with buffered one, but it didn't help. All channels are closed after completing a reading. The program recursively traverses folders. `cur.Ls(ctx)` return arrays of local files and of local dirs. The channel `dirQueue` is used as a queue

`Dir` and `File` interfaces

```
type File interface {
    // Name return a fully qualified file name
    Name() string
    // Stat returns a size of file or error
    Stat(ctx context.Context) (int64, error)
}

// Dir represent a dir object
type Dir interface {
    // Name return a fully qualified dir name
    Name() string
    // Ls return a set of Dir and a set of File or error if happened
    Ls(ctx context.Context) ([]Dir, []File, error)
}
```

Stack trace:

```
GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\...\go #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" test -c -o C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___Test_DirSizer_in_homework_storage.test.exe homework/storage #gosetup
"C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe" tool test2json -t C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___Test_DirSizer_in_homework_storage.test.exe -test.v -test.paniconexit0 -test.run ^\QTest_DirSizer\E$ #gosetup
=== RUN   Test_DirSizer
=== RUN   Test_DirSizer/ok,_file_storage
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc000045d40, {0x626e89?, 0x48e0d3?}, 0x650418)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1494 +0x37a
testing.runTests.func1(0xc000079710?)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1846 +0x6e
testing.tRunner(0xc000045d40, 0xc000107cd8)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1446 +0x10b
testing.runTests(0xc0000012c0?, {0x7b2aa0, 0x4, 0x4}, {0x19eaeb20108?, 0x40?, 0x0?})
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1844 +0x456
testing.(*M).Run(0xc0000012c0)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1726 +0x5d9
main.main()
    _testmain.go:53 +0x1aa

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc00014e000, {0x628032?, 0x7877a0?}, 0x6503f8)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1494 +0x37a
homework/storage.Test_DirSizer(0x0?)
    C:/Users/.../dir_sizer_test.go:19 +0x85
testing.tRunner(0xc00014e000, 0x650418)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1446 +0x10b
created by testing.(*T).Run
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1493 +0x35f

goroutine 7 [chan send]:
homework/storage.(*sizer).Size(0xc000055e50, {0x689600?, 0xc00005c240}, {0x688e08, 0xc000051030})
    C:/Users/.../dir_sizer.go:90 +0xe5
homework/storage.Test_DirSizer.func1(0x0?)
    C:/Users/.../dir_sizer_test.go:50 +0x610
testing.tRunner(0xc00014e340, 0x6503f8)
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1446 +0x10b
created by testing.(*T).Run
    C:/Program Files/Go/src/testing/testing.go:1493 +0x35f


Process finished with the exit code 1
```

Comment: please include a complete example that reproduces the problem.  I only see part of a program there

Comment: surely, I added more code

Comment: The stack trace will show exactly where all goroutines are waiting. What is blocked?

Comment: Look at the stack, you are blocked trying to send to `dirQueue`. You are sending before there are any receivers so it’s going to block.

Comment: You are also trying to close the channel by checking its length which doesn’t make sense, especially since the length is always 0 (even if it were buffered you can’t check the length and then make a decision based on that when there are concurrent operations). You are  sending values back into the unbuffered channel you read from which is bound to deadlock. I think you need to rethink this design

Comment: Thank you. I thought it over and rewrote it using a buffered channel